# Upgrading Powershell with choco is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, chocolatey

I am trying to update Powershell to version 4/5 on a Windows 7 machine.

From other StackOverflow posts, I created tried installing choco and then installing+upgrading powershell.

For instance

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
cinst powershell
```

And this

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
choco install powershell -n
choco upgrade powershell -n
```

Even after a restart, these have not upgraded my Powershell, even though they have downloaded successfully.

Is there another way to programmatically upgrade Powershell?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an actual deployment tool?  The WMF releases are OS patches, not software packages.  They also require a reboot to take effect.

Comment: Could you give an example of an actual deployment tool I could use?

Comment: WSUS, ideally..

Comment: To clarify, this update is not going to run on servers but for users machines (IT)

Comment: Why are you using the -n flag?  That tells Chocolatey to skip the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file, the file that would actually do the installation.  If you do `choco install powershell` it should work fine.  Where did you see the usage of the -n parameter?

Comment: Thank you so much. I misread the -n parameter as a way to force the install without having to press "y". Is there a way I can force the install so that someone doesn't have to be there to press "y"?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I just tried the following with a restart, but it did not update Powershell: `choco upgrade dotnet4.5 \f;
choco install powershell \f;
choco upgrade powershell \f;`

Comment: Can you grab the log file from the installation attempt and put it into a gist, or something like that, and then provide a link to it?

Comment: I realized the issue was that I had to restart cmd after installing choco and then install powershell. If answer the question I'll mark it as correct.